# install boost armhf from apt

Tags: boost, arm, cross-compiling

I want to install `libboost-dev-all:armhf` in my cross compilation environment. I started like this

```
sudo debootstrap stretch crossdev_folder
sudo chroot crossdev_folder
dpkg --add-architecture armhf
apt-get update
apt-get install libboost-all-dev:armhf
```

then I got this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-all-dev:armhf : Depends: libboost-graph-parallel-dev:armhf but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libboost-mpi-dev:armhf but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libboost-mpi-python-dev:armhf but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I installed `libboost-graph-parallel-dev` as suggested

```
apt-get install libboost-graph-parallel-dev:armhf
```

and it allowed me to continue with the installation of `libboost-dev-all:armhf`. However I got this error

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7-minimal.postinst: 42: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7-minimal.postinst: python2.7: Exec format error
dpkg: error processing package python2.7-minimal:armhf (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-minimal:armhf:
 python-minimal:armhf depends on python2.7-minimal (>= 2.7.13-1~); however:
  Package python2.7-minimal:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-minimal:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python2.7-minimal:armhf
 python-minimal:armhf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So as I understand `libboost-dev-all:armhf` requires `python2.7-minimal:armhf` and `python-minimal:armhf` to work, so apt tries to install them together with boost libraries. However,  during their installation, those broken packages are trying to execute some script situated at /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7-minimal.postinst, which is a shell script that in its 42 line does

```
if [ -n "$files" ]; then
    python2.7 -E -S /usr/lib/python2.7/py_compile.py $files
    ^^^^^^^^^
    if grep -sq '^byte-compile[^#]*optimize' /etc/python/debian_config; then
        python2.7 -E -S -O /usr/lib/python2.7/py_compile.py $files
    fi
else
```

trying to call python2.7 which is previously installed (also by boost) as armhf, removing the previous installation for amd. In consequence, as it is an armhf exec it cannot run in amd so it throws an `Exec format error` and everything fails.

Has somebody managed to install libboost-dev-all:armhf from apt?

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced a similar situation a while ago. Now I do build it manually (and with docker, but not relevant to this question). Here a helper script to crosscompile it supposing the `arm-linux-gnueabihf` toolchains are installed in the system. Boost headers, static and shared libraries will be installed in the prefix path (for example `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf`).

```
#!/bin/bash

boost_version=1.79.0
boost_dir=boost_1_79_0

wget https://freefr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/boost/boost/${boost_version}/${boost_dir}.tar.gz
tar xfz ${boost_dir}.tar.gz
rm ${boost_dir}.tar.gz
cd ${boost_dir}
./bootstrap.sh
echo "using gcc : arm : /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ ;" > user-config.jam 
sudo ./b2 toolset=gcc-arm --user-config=user-config.jam --without-python --prefix=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf install
cd ..
sudo rm -rf ${boost_dir} 
sudo ldconfig
```